# I am not able to pass data from one activity to another using bundles

Tags: android, android-studio

**This is the error's log:**

> I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9226(1168KB)
>   AllocSpace objects, 4(84KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 47MB/47MB, paused
>   1.006ms total 123.548ms
>
> W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.356ms
>
> W/ArrayMap: New hash 0 is before end of array hash 6295518 at index 4
>   key 
>                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: here
>                                                                          at android.util.ArrayMap.append(ArrayMap.java:494)
>                                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2483)
>                                                                          at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
>                                                                          at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:918)
>                                                                          at
>   eorder.nm.com.mealplanz.activity.LoginActivity.getDataFromOtherActivity(LoginActivity.java:180)
>                                                                          at
>   eorder.nm.com.mealplanz.activity.LoginActivity.initialize(LoginActivity.java:93)
>                                                                          at
>   eorder.nm.com.mealplanz.activity.BaseActivityNew.onCreate(BaseActivityNew.java:70)
>                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
>                                                                          at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
>                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
>                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
>                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)

**This is the code where I fill the `Bundle`:**

```
private void gotoLoginActivity() {

    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putString(AppConstant.CLASSFROM, AppConstant.LOGINACTIVITY);
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList(AppConstant.CARTLIST, orderCartDomains);
    bundle.putDouble(AppConstant.TOTALPRICE, totalprice);
    bundle.putDouble(AppConstant.TAXPRICE, tax);
    bundle.putDouble(AppConstant.SUBGRANDTOTAL, subtotal);


    loginIntent.putExtras(bundle);

    startActivity(loginIntent);
    finish();
}
```

**This is where I try to get data from the `Bundle`:**

```
private void getDataFromOtherActivity() {

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    classFrom = bundle.getString(AppConstant.CLASSFROM);

    if (classFrom.equalsIgnoreCase(AppConstant.ITEMACTIVITY)) {
        orderCartDomains = bundle.getParcelableArrayList(AppConstant.CARTLIST);
        totalrice = bundle.getDouble(AppConstant.TOTALPRICE);
        subgrandtotal = bundle.getDouble(AppConstant.SUBGRANDTOTAL);
        taxprice = bundle.getDouble(AppConstant.TAXPRICE);

    } else if (classFrom.equalsIgnoreCase(AppConstant.LOGINACTIVITY)) {
        orderCartDomains = bundle.getParcelableArrayList(AppConstant.CARTLIST);
        totalrice = bundle.getDouble(AppConstant.TOTALPRICE);
        subgrandtotal = bundle.getDouble(AppConstant.SUBGRANDTOTAL);
        taxprice = bundle.getDouble(AppConstant.TAXPRICE);

    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use intent for navigation and passing data from one activity to another

Comment: same exception I am getting

Comment: Remove this line and try..."bundle.putParcelableArrayList(AppConstant.CARTLIST, orderCartDomains);"

Comment: Hey, were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Hope This code helps**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putString("name", "Android");
bundle.putString("iname", "iPhone");
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);

// In ActivityB.class
public Bundle getBundle = null;
getBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

String name = getBundle.getString("name");
String id = getBundle.getString("iname");
```